# c Segmentation fault in macOS ; sometimes, and sometimes not

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

```
  void makeDouble(int **a, int *size){
    int i, j;
    *size *= 2;
    *a = (int *)realloc(*a, (*size)*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0; i<*size/2; i++){
        (*a)[*size/2+i] = (*a)[i] * 2;
    }

    int temp;
    for(i=0; i<*size-1; i++){
        for(j=0; j<*size-i-1; j++){
            if((*a)[j]>(*a)[j+1]){
                temp = (*a)[j];
                (*a)[j] = (*a)[j+1];
                (*a)[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

$
this is my code. What I wanted to do is getting a size and input as size, then making them all doubled, and sorting them.

But when I compile this, sometimes it collapses with segmentation fault and sometimes doesn't. And sometimes, it says "malloc: *** error for object 0x7fda70c02730: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6"
Why and What can I do with this? Sorry if my question is bad, I'm beginner with c.

Comment: You shouldn't cast the result of `malloc`, also your program leaks if `realloc` returns `NULL`.

Comment: '*size/2+i' not sure how that is evaluated. precedence/association wise?

Comment: @nullp0tr Do you say line 9 and line 32 occur this problem? then how can I fix it? ;(

Answer (score 1):

## First Segfault

One place where this would cause a segfault for sure is:

```
int size;
scanf("%d", &size);
int* a = (int *)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
```

if you pass it a character instead of a number that fits into an integer this would fail, because scanf is not gonna write to size.

You have to check the return of `scanf` which is the number of input items successfully matched:

```
if (scanf("%d", &size) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Supplied size is not a valid number.\n");
    return 1; 
}
```

## Memory Leak

if `realloc` returns NULL because it failed to allocate enough space, you get a memory leak because you do:

```
int *a = realloc(a, ...);
```

This pattern is buggy, because assigning the return of `realloc` to the array you wanna reallocate means you lose the reference to the allocated array since `a == NULL`. Do:

```
int *temp = realloc(a, ...);
if (temp == NULL) {
    free(a); // Or continue using it ..
} else {
    a = temp;
}
```

## Heap Corruption

Your function `makeDouble` is causing a heap corruption because you're accessing and modifying out of bound memory. I'm getting a `realloc() abort: invalid next size` with `glibc`, so you're most likely smashing the heap already allocated by the runtime, but not reaching the next page, hence no Segfault and a runtime error instead.

Comment: You still have lots of other issues in the code, you have a heap corruption.